# My hard disk with Vista and Wubi is failing, how can I use Wubi to rescue it?

Tags: windows, wubi, live-cd, disk

Can I just drag stuff to the 'host' folder? (which contains my windows files)
or some other way?

I have windows vista and the hard disk is dying (the annoying **'a hard disk is reporting health problems'** popup keeps coming on)

I can access ubuntu, but when i try to boot windows vista i just get an endless black screen current pending sector count and number of reallocated sectors are failing
**'overall assessment: DISK FAILURE IS IMMINENT'**

Comment: You should never fix a disk with the disk that is having problems, use a livecd instead.

Comment: i originally asked how to add more space to ubuntu also D:

Comment: what about using the host folder?somehow aquiring the host folder's space?

Comment: i don't want to lose the data to remove the pending sectors, and i think my dad would say i have 'nothing important'on the laptop (presario C700)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be better off using the Ubuntu live CD to explore and backup your data so you can replace your disk.

An external drive would be helpful here, to back up too, as your optical drive will have the Live CD in it and your hard drive is failing.

Comment: i have no cd of it, I just downloaded wubi and the ISO

Comment: [content deleted]